# DatabaseLink`: MySQL query with client/server compression

Tags: databaselink, sql, compression

I'm trying to reduce transfer time when accessing rows of a mysql table over a network, where each row has a lot of data. Is there a way to enable [client-server compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506460/when-should-i-use-mysql-compressed-protocol) when accessing a mysql database via ``DatabaseLink```?

As a workaround, I could request a column with `COMPRESS(column_with_lots_of_data)` in my `SQLExecute` query, but it is not clear how to uncompress the result on the Mathematica side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official [documentation for `MySQL Connector/J`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) has the answer. Setting the `useCompression` connection property to `true` enables zlib compression between client and server.

You can set this property when creating a new resource name:

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]
DatabaseExplorer[]
```

From the menu, open a connection, click "New", then "Next", give the source a name, and select "MySQL(Connector/J)" as the type. Specify the host info, user, password, database, and when prompted for connection properties, click "Add Property", and set the property name to `useCompression` and the value to `true`.

I've seen speedups of 70% when transferring large amounts of data (your mileage may vary).

Alternatively, client/server compression can be set programmatically using [`WriteDataSource`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/DatabaseLink/ref/WriteDataSource.html):

```
WriteDataSource["testSQL", "MySQL(Connector/J)", URL -> "main/test", 
    Username -> "user", Password -> "password", Location -> "System",
    "Properties"->{"useCompression"->"true"}]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can decompress on the *Mathematica* side easily.

Compressed MySQL reply has the following format:

- first four bytes are size of uncompressed data (lowest byte first)
- the rest is the string compressed with deflate algorithm (zlib library)

Here is an example of a reply:

> {10, 0, 0, 0, 120, 156, 243, 72, 205, 201, 201, 87, 240, 170, 112, 82, 4, 0, 19, 42, 3, 58}

To decompress it in *Mathematica* you can use `` Developer`RawUncompress `` function.

```
FromCharacterCode[Developer`RawUncompress[Drop[%, 4]]]
```

Comment: Nick, your ``Developer`RawUncompress` is useful, and I've been using it. But this afternoon I found the answer to the question on client/server compress in the official Connector/J docs.